# C - realloc not reflecting back to main

Tags: c, function, pointers, malloc, realloc

I am currently learning how dynamic memory management is working, more specifically realloc and how it is done in functions.

In following program I just wanted to try to allocate some numbers in function a() using malloc and then pass them to another function b(). In b() I pass the address of the pointer to c() in order to realloc the memory twice the size and initialise it with numbers.

Now coming to my question: why does the output in function b() show the correct numbers, but in the main function it does not? Shouldn't the pointer "numbers" in main also be pointing to the reallocated memory?

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 3

int a(int **numbers);
int b(int *numbers);
int c(int **numbers);

int main()
{
  int *numbers = NULL;

  a(&numbers);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < 2 * SIZE; i++)
    printf("In main after a: %i\n", numbers[i]);

  b(numbers);

  for(size_t i = 0; i <  2 * SIZE; i++)
    printf("In main after b: %i\n", numbers[i]);

  return 0;
}

int a(int **numbers)
{
  *numbers = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(numbers));
  if(!numbers)
  {
    free(numbers);
    return -1;
  }


  for(size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    (*numbers)[i] = i;

  return 0;
}

int b(int *numbers)
{
  c(&numbers);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < 2 * SIZE; i++)
    printf("In b after c: %i\n", numbers[i]);

  return 0;
}

int c(int **numbers)
{
  int *n_new = realloc(*numbers, 2 * SIZE * sizeof(numbers));
  if(!n_new)
  {
    free(n_new);
    return -1;
  }

  for(size_t i = 0; i < 2 * SIZE; i++)
    n_new[i] = i * 2;

  *numbers = n_new;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
In main after a: 0
In main after a: 1
In main after a: 2
In main after a: 0
In main after a: 0
In main after a: 0
In b after c: 0
In b after c: 2
In b after c: 4
In b after c: 6
In b after c: 8
In b after c: 10
In main after b: 0
In main after b: 0
In main after b: 2
In main after b: 0
In main after b: 0
In main after b: 0
```

Comment: Uh... Compare the parameters of `a` and `b`, and see how they are different. That difference is why `a` can change the pointer value from `main`, but `b` can not.

Comment: *Shouldn't the pointer "numbers" in main also be pointing to the reallocated memory?* No. Do you know what "call by value" is?

Comment: Or is your question actually, what's the difference between `int **numbers` and `int *numbers`?

Comment: What is the point of freeing a NULL pointer when malloc or realloc fails?

Comment: Before you go with `malloc` and its Family you should learn about Function return type. Learn the difference between `int` and `void` and where do you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the pointer by pointer to `b()` as well.  As it stands, calling `b(pointer)` cannot modify pointer in `main()`.  Do it the same way you call `a(&pointer)` instead.

Also, do not bother to call `free()` on pointers you know are null (when malloc has failed).  It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Does this mean I have to add one pointer per function if I want to realloc it in later functions? For example, I want to realloc the pointer *p, which was declared in function a(), in function d(). Then I would pass a(&p) -> b(&p) -> c(&p) and then realloc in d? Then I would have a 4-times pointer (****p) declared in d?

Comment: @sic: No, you can always pass it as `&p`.  Try it.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response, I will try it out!

Comment: Ok, now it works. Thank you very much, this helped a lot!